# awk to find date difference from two column

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I have file with values in below format-

```
datecolumn1     datecolumn2
20140202 20180113
20140202 20180113
20140202 20180113
20131202 20180113
20140331 20180113
```

I want to subtract $3-$2 to find total number of days. output will be as below-

```
20180113 20180115 3.
```

please help with awk command.

Comment: What have you tried? Using the column values as input to `date -d` will work fine. Subtract the resulting seconds since epoch, take the absolute value (or handle before/after however you like) and then convert the resulting seconds difference to days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same, to get the difference of days between dates(format which you have posted in your post). Also this code is created and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
TZ=PST awk '
FNR>1{
  split($1,date,"");
  split($2,date1,"");
  print (mktime(date1[1] date1[2] date1[3] date1[4]" " date1[5] date1[6]" " date1[7] date1[8] " " "00 00 00")\
  -mktime(date[1] date[2] date[3] date[4]" " date[5] date[6]" " date[7] date[8] " " "00 00 00"))\
  /(24*60*60);
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: for data like  20 20180110 20180113; how to print 20 3 (first field and date difference)

Comment: That will get a count of 86400 second intervals between midnight on 2 dates but that's not the same as a count of days and the result won't always be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNUawk, `mkdate` and `FIELDWIDTHS` for separating the the date parts. As `$4` is a space, it is abused as a space in `mktime` as it is shorter to write than `" "` (:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2 1 4 2 2" }
{
    print $0,(mktime($5 $4 $6 $4 $7 " 0 0 0")-mktime($1 $4 $2 $4 $3 " 0 0 0"))/86400
}' file
datecolumn1     datecolumn2 0
20140202 20180113 1441
20140202 20180113 1441
20140202 20180113 1441
20131202 20180113 1503
20140331 20180113 1384.04  # wut?
20180113 20180115 2
```

(I was not really sure if `20180113 20180115` should produce `3` as in the example or `2` as math dictates.)

Comment: The `wut?` line is because there's not always 86400 seconds between days. Consider DST and leap-seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function secs(d) { return mktime(substr(d,1,4)" "substr(d,5,2)" "substr(d,7)" 0 0 0") }
{ print $1, $2, int((secs($2) - secs($1)) / (24 * 60 * 60)) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
datecolumn1 datecolumn2 0
20140202 20180113 1441
20140202 20180113 1441
20140202 20180113 1441
20131202 20180113 1503
20140331 20180113 1384
```

Note that the above is an **approximation** to the number of days difference but it does not account accurately for DST. I just used it since you seem happy with that approximation but if you wanted the result to be accurate you'd need a different time calculation that would involve using `strftime("%j")` for the start date, the last day of that year minus that value (to get the number of days remaining that year), the last day of every year between the start and end dates, and the day of the year for the end date.