# awk for finding date difference in days from two column

Tags: awk

For date like

```
20 20180110 20180113
100 20180110 20180115
9 20180110 20180114
```

desired output

```
20 20180110 20180113 3
100 20180110 20180115 5
9 20180110 20180114 4
```

pls help me to with awk command.

Comment: Oh come on, you didn't seriously need to ask a whole new question for data in fields 2 and 3 [instead of fields 1 and 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48257629/1745001). **Think** about it and try to solve it yourself and you'll probably get it done in less time than it took you to post this question. The accepted answers in both questions won't give you an accurate number of days btw due to leap seconds and DST. Think about that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **GNU awk**, `mktime()` and `substr()` function

Input:

```
$ cat file
20 20180110 20180113
100 20180110 20180115
9 20180110 20180114
```

Output:

```
awk 'function df(v){ return mktime(substr(v,1,4)" "substr(v,5,2)" "substr(v,7,2)" "0" "0" "0)  }{print $0,(df($3)-df($2))/86400}' file
20 20180110 20180113 3
100 20180110 20180115 5
9 20180110 20180114 4
```

Better Readable:

```
awk '
    function df(v)
    {
      return mktime(substr(v,1,4)" "substr(v,5,2)" "substr(v,7,2)" "0" "0" "0)  
    }
    {
      print $0,(df($3)-df($2))/86400
    }
    ' file
```

Comment: That will get a count of 86400 second intervals between midnight on 2 dates but that's not the same as a count of days and the result won't always be an integer.